# Is there a specific liturgy for a Corpus Christi procession?

Tags: catholicism, liturgy, processions

I'm helping to plan a Corpus Christi procession in a few weeks, just wondering if there is an official way of doing it - or even a traditional way of doing it that corresponds to our community's fairly diverse make up, we are Parthians and Medes.... Just Kidding, our parish is we're half German, half Irish and half Mexican. Half of us don't sing and half of us don't sing in the same language.  So sound liturgical advice, as well tradition would be appreciated.

Comment: Yea for a new tag "processions".  We need more questions about this aspect of Christianity: public display.  I heard good things about the long tradition of [St. Joseph processions in Louisiana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_Joseph%27s_Day#United_States).   There is also this [Louisiana annual Eucharistic Procession](https://www.newliturgicalmovement.org/2022/08/eucharistic-procession-by-boat-in.html).

Comment: You can probably call either the rector of the local cathedral or the music director there. Either should be a good resource on the rubrics. Both should have led or helped MC multiple ones in the past. I know that the RCAN also has its own, full-time, MC, but it's an archdiocese.

Answer (score 1):

**Is there a specific liturgy for a Corpus Christi procession?**

According to the Extraordinary Form **yes**. The Ordinary Form follows similar norms with more general leeway for popular devotional interpretation of the same norms and with vernacular hymns if needed.

There are general guidelines from the **Directory on Popular Piety and the Liturgy** (Vatican City December 2001) and the ***Romanum Rituale*** of Pope Pius V.

This is going to be a rather long answer as I would like it to be something complete for many to have as a reference.

***Catholic Culture*** has some general liturgical norms in English about the liturgical aspects of the procession. We can look at various different hymns further on.

> [**Eucharistic Procession on the Feast of Corpus Christi**](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/liturgicalyear/prayers/view.cfm?id=1198#:%7E:text=Only%20eucharistic%20banners%20should%20be,those%20walking%20in%20the%20procession.)
>
> **Prayer**:
>
> 695. The public procession of the Eucharist should be promoted everywhere, especially in the light of the example of Pope John Paul II, who took the annual Corpus Christi procession from St. Peter's Square to the streets of Rome . However, such a procession must be carefully planned. If it passes "through the streets", i.e., outside church property, it may be authorized only by the diocesan bishop, who should establish appropriate regulations to ensure respect for the Eucharist, a dignified celebration and full participation on the part of the people . What is described below for the solemnity of the Body and Blood of the Lord (Corpus Christi) may be used on other major occasions when this act of homage to Our Lord may also be celebrated, for example, "after a lengthy period of adoration", such as the annual solemn exposition or Forty Hours devotion.
> 696. Everything is prepared as usual: (a) for a solemn Mass with white vestments and (b) for exposition of the Eucharist. Six or four candles burn on the altar. An extra priest's host is placed on the paten or prepared in a lunette, to be consecrated for the procession. The monstrance is ready on a credence table. Extra candles and flowers may be set up in the sanctuary to enhance the festive occasion. A white cope may be placed near the chair.
>
> Preparations for the Procession 697. In the sacristy, a second thurible is prepared during Communion. The two thurifers should be assisted by a boat bearer during the procession. A noble canopy (baldachin) attached to four or six staffs may be prepared outside the sanctuary, preferably near the seats of the people trained to carry it. Torch bearers should assist as for solemn Mass. Glasses to protect the torches or lanterns mounted on staffs may be used according to custom. Only eucharistic banners should be carried in the procession, never images of Our Lady or the saints. Banners of sodalities and Catholic movements may be carried by their representatives. A eucharistic banner may replace the processional cross. Hand candles are usually carried by those walking in the procession. If it is customary for children, such as first communicants, to strew flowers before the Eucharist, they should be trained to act in an orderly and reverent way, without impeding the procession. Members of the armed forces, the police, scouts or other bodies may escort the procession through the streets. Music may he provided by a choir and/or band, according to custom.
>
> 698. The route of the procession must be carefully defined. Well-placed loudspeakers and printed programs promote the full participation of the people-and help those watching the procession to be drawn into the celebration. In some countries, it is customary to decorate the houses and other buildings along the route . If the procession is long, the celebrant may stop at "altars" set up at convenient places where Benediction is given. The procession terminates with solemn Benediction, given either in or outside the church where it began, at another church or at some suitable place where the people can gather conveniently.
>
> The Mass 699. The principal Mass of the solemnity of the Body and Blood of Christ is celebrated, according to local custom. In the homily, the theological and spiritual significance of the procession should be explained. Directions to assist the faithful to take part should be provided at the time of the homily or set out in the program with the hymns and acclamations to he sung (luring the procession which should focus on the Lord .
>
> 700. At the fraction, the Host for the procession is either set apart on a paten or placed in the lunette (unless already consecrated in it). During Communion a server brings the empty monstrance to the altar, genuflects and places it to the left of the corporal. The missal and stand are removed.
>
> In the sacristy, the two thurifers prepare the thuribles with an ample supply of charcoal and bring them to the sanctuary, leading the torch bearers, unless they have remained in the sanctuary since the Eucharistic Prayer. The ablutions are best carried out at the credence table. Clergy who are not concelebrants may put on white copes for the procession, but not eucharistic vestments which are reserved for concelebrants. Hand candles are distributed and lit.
>
> 701. The deacon or, lacking him, the celebrant, goes to the altar, places the Host in the monstrance, sets the monstrance on the corporal and genuflects. The deacon then goes to the chair, where the celebrant sings or says the Prayer after Communion. The blessing and dismissal are omitted. At the chair, the celebrant may remove the chasuble and put on a white cope. If the monstrance is heavy or the procession will he long, a sling may be put around his neck, over the stole, to take the weight of the monstrance. Directed by the M.C., the cross bearer and candle bearers take up a position in the aisle of the church, where they will lead the procession from the church.") Concelebrants and other clergy follow them and line up in the aisle, so that they will precede the canopy. The celebrant, deacon(s), M.C., torch hearers and thurifers line up in front of the altar, genuflect and then kneel.
>
> The Procession 702. All kneel while a hymn of adoration is sung. Incense is prepared as at exposition, but in two thuribees. The Host is incensed as usual. Then the deacon or, if he is not present, a concelebrant or assistant priest goes to the altar with the celebrant. Both genuflect, and the deacon (concelebrant or assistant priest) places the monstrance in the celebrant's veiled hands. If he has no assisting clergy, the celebrant himself goes to the altar to take the monstrance in his veiled hands. If a sling is used, the deacon or the M.C. ensures that the monstrance rests securely in it, under the humeral veil.
>
> 703. All taking part in the procession stand. The celebrant turns or comes around to the front of the altar. His cope is held back by the deacon(s) as he slowly walks forward to an agreed point, where those bearing the canopy meet him and raise it over him and the deacon(s). The two thurifers and the boat bearer take their places in front of the canopy. As the first hymn begins, the procession proceeds in this order:
> 704. the cross bearer carrying the cross or banner, flanked by the candle bearers;
> 705. religious associations, sodalities, etc., perhaps carrying their own banners;
> 706. religious in their habits;
> 707. the clergy, in choir dress (and copes);
> 708. the concelebrants of the Mass;
> 709. the two thurifers in front of the canopy, customarily swinging the thuribles with their inside hands . (Note: They should not walk backwards. But the boat bearer walks to one side of them, not at the center. When required, he goes to the thurifiers and places incense in the thuribles in the course of the procession.)
> 710. Directly under the canopy walks the celebrant, carrying the Eucharist devoutly at eye-level, with the deacon(s) beside and slightly behind him, holding back his cope, if necessary. No one else walks beneath the canopy. The torch bearers with torches or lanterns walk along each side of the canopy. According to local custom, an escort from the armed forces, the police, scouts or a Catholic youth movement, etc., may also flank the canopy, but arranged farther out from the torch bearers and carefully spaced so as not to obscure the celebrant as he carries the Eucharist.
> 711. Directed by the ushers in the church, the people who are to walk in the procession follow the canopy, taking part in hymns and acclamations. The singing is led by the choir and cantor(s) — either walking in the midst of the people or singing from a fixed point, with appropriate amplification. The procession should move at a slow and reverent pace. Identifiable marshalls should control the ranks of a large procession, so that it does not become disordered. All those in the procession not already carrying something may carry a hand candle. Children trained to strew flowers are arranged according to local custom, but they are not mingled with the clergy or servers.
> 712. If the bishop carries the monstrance, he is flanked by two assistant deacons in dalmatics (or, lacking deacons, concelebrants), who walk beside and slightly behind him holding back his cope. There are some other variations in the order of procession. The clergy in choir dress are followed by the deacon(s) of the Mass, then the canons of the cathedral chapter and other priests, wearing copes, followed by visiting bishops wearing copes, but bareheaded, walking immediately in front of the thurifers. Those of higher rank walk nearer the Blessed Sacrament . Other visiting bishops wear choir dress but are bareheaded during the procession and immediately follow the canopy. Those of higher rank also walk nearer the Blessed Sacrament, in this case preceding others in the order of procession .
> 713. If the bishop does not carry the monstrance, he walks alone immediately before the canopy, bareheaded and carrying his crozier, but not blessing the people. If he celebrated the Mass, he wears vestments, otherwise a white cope. A bishop in choir dress comes immediately after the canopy.
> 714. As the procession goes through the streets or appointed area, the faithful not walking in it should kneel as the Blessed Eucharist passes by. As noted above, the procession may pause at suitably decorated "altars" for Benediction.
> 715. On returning to the church, or arriving at another church chosen and prepared for the final Benediction, the ceremonial escort, torch bearers and thurifers precede the canopy if the aisle is narrow. The canopy bearers stop in front of the sanctuary as the celebrant goes up to the altar. They move off to one side and put the canopy in a suitable place. The deacon takes the monstrance from the celebrant, places it on the corporal, and both genuflect. The M.C. or a server removes the humeral veil. Servers and torch bearers line up in the sanctuary for Benediction.
> 716. The celebrant and deacon(s) should wait until all the people have taken their places in the church and are kneeling. At a signal from the M.C., the hymn of adoration is sung, the Eucharist is incensed and Benediction is given as usual. Unless adoration is to continue, the Eucharist is reposed and a final hymn, acclamation or Marian antiphon may be sung. Clergy and servers proceed to the sacristy.
> 717. If the final Benediction is given in the open air, from the church steps, a balcony or other place, these arrangements are adapted accordingly. The Benediction hymn begins only once all the people have gathered, kneeling or standing in an orderly way in the designated area. After Benediction, the Eucharist is taken privately to the nearest tabernacle for reposition.

The above guidelines can be tweaked according to necessity and local traditions.

The [**Directory on Popular Piety and the Liturgy**](https://www.vatican.va/roman_curia/congregations/ccdds/documents/rc_con_ccdds_doc_20020513_vers-direttorio_en.html) under Pope John Paul II states the following:

> *Solemnity of the Body and Blood of Christ*
>
> For centuries, the celebration of Corpus Christi remained the principal point of popular piety's concentration on the Eucharist. In the sixteenth and seventeenth centuries, faith, in reaction to various forms of protestantism, and culture (art, folklore and literature) coalesced in developing lively and significant expressions Eucharistic devotion in popular piety.
>
> 161. Eucharistic devotion, which is so deeply rooted in the Christian faithful, must integrate two basic principles:
>
> - the supreme reference point for Eucharistic devotion is the Lord's Passover; the Pasch as understood by the Fathers, is the feast of Easter, while the Eucharist is before all else the celebration of Paschal Mystery or of the Passion, Death and Resurrection of Christ;
> - all forms of Eucharisit devotion must have an intrinsic reference to the Eucharistic Sacrifice, or dispose the faithful for its celebration, or prolong the worship which is essential to that Sacrifice.
>
> Hence, the Rituale Romanum states "The faithful, when worshipping Christ present in the Sacrament of the Altar, should recall that this presence comes from the Sacrifice of the Eucharist, and tends towards sacramental and spiritual communion".
>
> 162. The Corpus Christi procession represents the typical form of an Eucharistic procession. It is a prolongation of the celebration of the Eucharist: immediately after Mass, the Sacred Host, consecrated during the Mass, is borne out of the Church for the Christian faithful "to make public profession of faith and worship of the Most Blessed Sacrament".
>
> The faithful understand and appreciate the values inherent in the procession: they are aware of being "the People of God", journeying with the Lord, and proclaiming faith in him who has become truly "God-amongst-us".
>
> It is necessary however to ensure that the norms governing processions be observed, especially those ensuring respect for the dignity and reverence of the Blessed Sacrament. It is also necessary to ensure that the typical elements of popular piety accompanying the precession, such as the decoration of the streets and windows with flowers and the hymns and prayers used during the procession, truly "lead all to manifest their faith in Christ, and to give praise to the Lord", and exclude any forms of competition.
>
> 163. The Eucharistic procession is normally concluded by a blessing with the Blessed Sacrament. In the specific case of the Corpus Christi procession, the solemn blessing with the Blessed Sacrament concludes the entire celebration: the usual blessing by the priest is replaced by the blessing with the Blessed Sacrament.
>
> It is important that the faithful understand that this blessing is not an independent form of Eucharistic piety, but the end of a prolonged act of worship. Hence, liturgical norms prohibit "exposition of the Blessed Sacrament for the purpose of giving the blessing".

For the last reference I am going to employ the Latin texts of the [*Romanum Rituale*](http://laudatedominum.net/files/romy.pdf) as it is harder to find and the English versions are easily found online. The traditional Latin hymns are mentioned below, as well as the fact that the Litany of Saints can be sung, especially on long processions.

> **De Processione in Festo Ssmi Corpus Christi**
>
> 1. Decenter ornentur ecclesiæ et parietes viarum, per quas est transeundum, tapetibus et aulæis, et sacris imaginibus, non autem profanis aut vanis figuris, seu indignis ornamentis.
> 2. Sacerdos primum Missam celebret, in qua duas hostias consecret, et sumpta una, alteram in tabernaculum in Processione deferendum ita reponat, ut per vitrum seu crystallum, quo ipsum tabernaculum circumseptum esse debet. exterius adorantibus appareat.
>
> Peracto autem Sacrificio, et Processione jam inchoata, ordine, quo jam supra dictum est in Litaniis majoribus, Sacerdos pluviali albo indutus, ter incenset Sacramentum.
>
> 3. Deinde unus e Clericis oblongum ac decens velum circumponit scapulis Sacerdotis. qui parte veli ante pectus pendente, utraque manu cooperta, ostensorium seu tabernaculum a Diacono sibi porrectum reverenter suscipit: mox Sacramentum ante faciem tenens, vertit se ad populum: inde procedit sub umbellam comitantibus Ministris, et duo acolythi vel Clerici cum thuribulis fumantibus præcedunt.
> 4. Omnes procedunt nudo capite, accensos cereos gestantes, et sequentes Hymnos pro longitudine Processionis devote concinentes. Dum vero Sacerdos discedit ab Altari, Clerus, vel Sacerdos cantare incipit sequentem Hymnum:
>
> [**Pange, lingua, gloriósi
> Córporis mystérium**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pange_lingua_gloriosi_corporis_mysterium),
> Sanguinísque pretiósi,
> Quem in mundi prétium
> Fructus ventris generósi
> Rex effúdit géntium.
>
> Nobis datus, nobis natus Ex intácta Vírgine, Et in mundo conversátus, Sparso verbi sémine, Sui moras incolátus Miro clausit órdine.
>
> In suprémæ nocte cœnæ, Recúmbens cum frátribus, Observáta lege plene Cibis in legálibus,
> Cibum turbæ duodénæ Se dat suis mánibus.
>
> Verbum caro, panem verum Verbo carnem éfficit:
> Fitque sanguis Christi merum, Et si sensus déficit, Ad firmándum cor sincérum Sola fides súfficit.
>
> Tantum ergo Sacraméntum Venerémur cérnui:
> Et antíquum docúmentum Novo cedat rítui:
> Præstet fides suppleméntum Sénsuum deféctui.
>
> Genitóri, Genitóque
> Laus et jubilátio,
> Salus, honor, virtus quoque Sit et benedíctio: Procedénti ab utróque Compar sit laudátio. Amen.
>
> Noctis recólitur cœna novíssima,
> Qua Christus créditur agnum et ázyma Dedísse fráatribus, juxta legítima Priscis indúlta pátribus.
>
> Post agnum týpicum, explétis épulis, Corpus Domínicum datum discípulis, Sic totum ómnibus, quod totum síngulis, Ejus fatémur mánibus.
>
> Dedit fragílibus córporis férculum, Dedit et trístibus sánguinis póculum, Dicens: Accípite quod trado vásculum, Omnes ex eo bíbite.
>
> Sic sacrifícium istud instítuit,
> Cujus offícium commítti vóluit
> Solis presbýteris, quibus sic cóngruit, Ut sumant, et dent céteris.
>
> Panis angélicus fit panis hóminum; Dat panis cǽlicus figúris términum: O res mirábilis! mandúcat Dóminum Pauper servus et húmilis.
>
> Te, trina Déitas únaque, póscimus,
> Sic nos tu vísita, sicut te cólimus:
> Per tuas sémitas due nos quo téndimus, Ad lucem, quam inhábitas. Amen.
>
> [**Verbum supernum prodiens**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verbum_supernum_prodiens),
> Nec Patris linquens dexteram,
> Ad opus suum exiens,
> Venit ad vitæ vesperam.
>
> In mortem a discípulo Suis tradéndus ǽmulis, Prius in vitæ férculo Se trádidit discípulis.
>
> Quibus sub bina spécie Carnem dedit et sánguinem: Ut dúplicis substántiæ Totum cibáret hóminem.
>
> Se nascens dedit sócium, Convéscens in edúlium, Se móriens in prétium,
> Se regnans dat in prǽmium.
>
> O salutáris hóstia,
> Quæ cæli pandis óstium, Bella premunt hostília, Da robur, fer auxílium.
>
> Uni trinóque Dómino, Sit sempitérna glória,
> Qui vitam sine término Nobis donet in pátria. Amen.
>
> **Salutis humanæ Sator**,
> Jesu, voluptas cordium,
> Orbis redempti Conditor,
> Et casta lux amantium:
>
> Qua victus es clémentia, Ut nostra ferres crímina? Mortem subíres ínnocens, A morte nos ut tólleres?
>
> Perrúmpis inférnum chaos; Vihctis cátenas détrahis; Victor triúmpho nóbili
> Ad déxteram Patris sedes.
>
> Te cogat indulgéntia,
> Ut damna nostra sárcias, Tuíque vultus cómpotes Dites beáto lúmine.
>
> Tu dux ad astra, et sémita,
> Sis meta nostris córdibus,
> Sis lacrimárum gáudium,
> Sis dulce vitæ prǽmium. Amen.
>
> **Aeterne rex altissime**,
> redemptor et fidelium,
> quo mors soluta deperit,
> datur triumphus gratiae.
>
> Ascéndis orbes síderum, Quo te vocábat cǽlitus Colláta, non humánitus, Rerum potéstas ómnium.
>
> Ut; trina renim máchina, Cæléstium, terréstrium, Et inferórum cóndita, Flectat genu jam súbdita.
>
> Tremunt vidéntes Angeli Versam vicem mortálium: Peccat caro, mundat caro, Regnat Deus Dei caro.
>
> Sis Ipse nostrum gáudium, Manens olýmpo prǽmium, Mundi regis qui fábricam, Mundána vincens gáudia
>
> Hinc te precántes quǽsumus, Ignósce culpis ómnibus, Et corda sursum súbleva
> Ad te supérna grátia.
>
> Ut cum repénte cœperis Clarére nube júdicis, Pœnas repéllas débitas, Reddas corónas pérditas.
>
> Jesu, tibi sit glória,
> Qui victor in cælum redis, Cum Patre, et almo Spíritu In sempitérna sǽcula. Amen.
>
> Te Deum laudámus, ut infra. Benedíctus Dóminus Deus Israël, ut supra  cum Glória Patri in fine.
>
> Magníficat ánima mea, Dóminum, ut supra  cum Glória Patri in fine.
>
> 5. Peractca Processione, et Sanctissimo Sacramento ad ecclesiam reportato, et super Altare deposito, omnes Ecclesiastici, qui adsint, hinc inde ordine genuflexi illud reverenter adorantes, dum Sacerdos de more incensat, sequentem Hymni partem concinant:
>    Tantum ergo Sacraméntum.
>    Venerémur cérnui:
>
> Et antíquum documéntum Novo cedat rítui:
> Præstet fides suppleméntum Sensuum deféctui.
>
> Genitóri, Genitóque
> Laus et jubilátio,
> Salus, honor, virtus quoque Sit, et benedíctio; Precedénti ab utróque Compar sit laudátio. Amen.
>
> Postea duo Clerici dicant:
>
> V. Panem de cælo præstitísti eis, allelúja.
>
> R Omne delectaméntum in se habéntem, allelúja. Deinde Sacerdos stans dicat:
>
> Oremus (Oratio):
>
> Deus, qui nobis sub Sacraménto mirábili, passiónis tuæ memóriam reliquísti: tríbue, quǽsumus, itanos Córporis et Sánguinis tui sacra mystéria venerári; ut redemptiónis tuæ fructum in nobis júgiter sentiámus: Qui vivis et regnas in sǽcula sæculórum.
>
> R Amen.
>
> 6. Tunc Sacerdos, facta genuflexione, cum Sacramento semel benedicat populum in modum crucis, nihil dicens; postea illud reverenter reponitur.
> 7. Hic autem modus benedicendi servatur etiam in aliis Processionibus faciendis cum Sanctissimo Sacramento.